# cannot hover with new div of fancybox 2

Tags: hover, fancybox

I've made it work by these codes for an addtional title (a new `div` inside `fancybox`):

```js
beforeShow: function(){
this.title=$(this.element).data('caption');
this.title2="<div class='photo_exif'>"+$(this.element).data('exif')+"</div>";
$(this.title2)
.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
return false; /* Disables right click */
})
.prependTo( $.fancybox.inner );
}
```

and the html is :

```html
<a href='PhotoURL' class='fancybox' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-caption='PhotoTitle' data-exif='photoTitle2'>pic</a>
```

now i want this `div` (`div.photo_exif`) `hover` to show or hide, so i added these codes:

```js
afterShow:function() {
$("#fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
$(".photo_exif").show();
}, function() {
$(".photo_exif").hide();
});
}
```

but it doesnt work. The `div` is always `show` on fancybox. My css is :

```css
.photo_exif {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
color: #fff;
width:100%;
height:30px;
background: #000;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

and my whole fancybox code (with ie6 crack) is :

```js
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
fitToView: false,
mouseWheel: false,
beforeShow: function(){
this.title=$(this.element).data('caption');
this.title2="<div class='photo_exif'>"+$(this.element).data('exif')+"</div>";
$(this.title2)
.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
return false; /* Disables right click */
})
.prependTo( $.fancybox.inner );
},
afterShow: function(){
if (jQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10) <= 6) {
$("div#fancybox-buttons").css("top", $("html").scrollTop());
$(window).scroll(function () {
$("div#fancybox-buttons").css("top", $("html").scrollTop());
});
}
$("#fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
$(".photo_exif").show();
}, function() {
$(".photo_exif").hide();
});
}  
});
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: You should mention the issues you are having.  Not asking if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This one was easy. This line of your code :

```
$("#fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
```

... should be :

```
$(".fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
```

The fancybox selector is a *class* not an *ID*